# How to add subnet description for an Active Directory site (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm creating a method to create Active Directory sites. It works fine to create a site, add subnets, create site link, etc... But I can't find a way to add a subnet description.

When I create the subnet I do:

```
var contextType = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Forest, "forest", "user","Password"]);
var site = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySite.FindByName(contextType, SiteCode);

foreach (string sn in Subnet)
{
    try
    {
        var subnet = new ActiveDirectorySubnet(contextType, sn, SiteCode);
        subnet.Location = Location;
        subnet.Save();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It adds the subnets in the list to the site, but I can't find a way to add the description.

The ActiveDirectorySubnet Class doesn't seem to have any property for the description, but it is there in the "Active Directory Sites and Services" UI...

Does anyone know where to save this information?

Answer (score 0):

It's a PowerShell but should be easy to translate to C# (this link might be useful http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315716)

```
$object = [adsi]'LDAP://CN=192.0.2.0\/24,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com'  
$object.description = "Test-net"  
$object.CommitChanges()
```

;-p

Answer (score 0):

Impove it.  Just play a bit with string

You can use it :

SetSubnetDescription("LDAP://CN=10.197.6.128\/25,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=test,DC=domain");

```
    public static  bool SetSubnetDescription(string Subnet)
    {
    try
    {
    DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry(Subnet);
    Object ads = ent.NativeObject;
    Type type = ads.GetType();
    type.InvokeMember("Description", 
        BindingFlags.SetProperty, 
        null, 
        ads, 
        new object[] {"your new description"});

    // The changes to the object must always be committed or else they 
    // will be lost.
    ent.CommitChanges(); 
    return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     return false;
    }
```